# AngularJS property change propagation

Tags: angular

I bit of newbie question, but I have already spent my day on it...

I have the following AngularJS2 app (using beta1):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <btn></btn>
  `,
  directives: [Button]
 })

 class AppComponent {}

 bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

and then I have the component defined like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'btn',
  template: `
    <div [hidden]="active">aaaa!</div>
    <button (click)="onClick()">Click Me</button>
    `
 })

export class Button {
  active: boolean = false;
  onClick() {
    this.active = true;
    console.log(1) //successfully logs 1 to the console
  }
```

}

And guess - the damn div won't hide.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you imported Component as so: `import {Component} from 'angular2/core'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how you are loading the angular libraries files via system js or by script tags ?
if systemjs i was having same issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6719

if by script tags probably you might try something like :

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UGCMTZ2RGIU4GiYntpm5?p=preview) I used.

Can you see if the `hidden` attribute in the in-memory DOM? I made my test with beta1 on Chrome.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely CSS issue or how browser interprets `[hidden]`. By default `<div>` has `display: block`; I also noticed sometimes `[hidden]` attribute is ignored with block elements. Your code [works here](http://plnkr.co/edit/T7Nqdo4CWjBmCQVb5AKR?p=preview) in Chrome.

You can add css class and it will be hidden:

```
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using webpack it turns out the issue is caused by missing the /angular2-polyfills.min.js file.

Thanks for the help!